# How can I return true boolean if a specific property is set to true in all objects of an array?

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have the following array:

```
let name = [
    { name: "One", active: true },
    { name: "Two", active: true },
    { name: "Three", active: true },
    { name: "Four", active: true },
    { name: "Five", active: true },
    { name: "Six", active: true },
]
```

Is it possible to iterate over it and return true if the active property of all objects is equal to true? Vise versa, return false if there's even a single false value.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Do some research on internet (`every()` and `some()` can be useful), then try it by yourself and if you find some issue, comeback to StackOverflow to ask how to solve the issue, not how to code everything.

Comment: `name.every(({active}) => active)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`every` is an array method that will test the truthiness of some predicate function for every item of an array. If the function returns a truthy value for each input, `every` return `true`; otherwise it returns `false`.

```
name.every(obj => obj.active)
```

Note that for an empty array, this will always be `true` ([vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for and very informative!